# Visual Studio 2015 tools for Xamarin Uninstall

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, uninstallation

I have Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin on my PC. VS 2015 has been long uninstalled but VS 2015 Tools for Xamarin keeps taking up space on my drive. Can I uninstall it or it will 'harm' my VS2017 installation in some way?

[image]

Also, I'm not sure if Microsoft VS2015 Shell (Isolated) is needed at all?
Can I get rid of both installations?

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't uninstall VS2015 completely and then try to install VS2017? if you didn't install VS2017 yet, feel free to uninstall VS2015 and its related component(s), VS2017 has no dependency on VS2015 and its component(s).

Comment: Uninstalling VS2015 Tools for Xamarin was ok, but VS2015 Shell Isolated is required by MS SQL Server, so don't uninstall.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling VS2015 Tools for Xamarin was ok, but VS2015 Shell Isolated is required by MS SQL Server, so don't uninstall.